# Is it possible to do train and test in real time in deep neural network?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

My question is about doing the train and then test it in real time instead of doing the training and then testing separately.

What I know, deep neural network in below code, is doing training first and then after finishing the training, it starts doing testing? that is My question, what's about if I want to do train every time and then if the output less than such threshold, test should be performed and so on.

```
### imports
import tensorflow as tf

### constant data
x  = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_ = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

### induction
# 1x2 input -> 2x3 hidden sigmoid -> 3x1 sigmoid output

# Layer 0 = the x2 inputs
x0 = tf.constant( x  , dtype=tf.float32 )
y0 = tf.constant( y_ , dtype=tf.float32 )

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [2,3] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b1 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
h1 = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( x0,m1 ) + b1 )

# Layer 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [3,1] , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
b2 = tf.Variable( tf.random_uniform( [1]   , minval=0.1 , maxval=0.9 , dtype=tf.float32  ))
y_out = tf.sigmoid( tf.matmul( h1,m2 ) + b2 )


### loss
# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square( y0 - y_out ) )

# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)


### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
  for step in range(500) :
    sess.run(train)

  results = sess.run([m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss])
  labels  = "m1,b1,m2,b2,y_out,loss".split(",")
  for label,result in zip(*(labels,results)) :
    print ""
    print label
    print result

print ""
```

For example, in the above example, the variable `loss` should be calculated and if it's less than `0.01`, test should be done, and every time should be calculate in order to perform the test.

Is that possible? how can I modify the below code to perform that?

thank you in advance

Comment: No, what you describe is close leakage which is bad.

Comment: what you mean close leakage? could you please describe more ?

Comment: Look it up, it's a textbook no no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you can achieve this easily.

```
loss_list = []
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for t in range(100):
        loss_val, _ = sess.run([loss, train])
        loss_list.append(loss_val)
```

Without changing the part that creates `tensorflow` graph, you only need to put `loss` inside `sess.run()`

As long as you know the real-time `loss` value, you can have another feed dictionary for test dataset (so I advise you not using `tf.constant`, but instead using `tf.placeholder` for feeding the data), and have another `sess.run` for computing the loss on testset.

**EDIT**

I have refactored your code, basically, I replaced `tf.constant` with `tf.placeholder`, so you can have multiple feed dictionaries interact with one `tensorflow` graph.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf

tf.reset_default_graph()

x_train = [[0.,0.],[1.,1.],[1.,0.],[0.,1.]]
y_train = [[0.],[0.],[1.],[1.]]

x_test =  [[0.,0.],[.5,.5],[.5,0.],[0.,.5]]
y_test = [[0.],[0.],[2.],[2.]]

# use placeholder instead so you can have different inputs
x = tf.placeholder('float32', [None, 2])
y = tf.placeholder('float32',)

# Layer 1 = the 2x3 hidden sigmoid
m1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([2,3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x, m1) + b1)
# Layer 2 = the 3x1 sigmoid output
m2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([3,1], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([1], minval=0.1, maxval=0.9, dtype=tf.float32))
y_out = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(h1, m2) + b2)
### loss
# loss : sum of the squares of y0 - y_out
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - y_out))
# training step : gradient decent (1.0) to minimize loss
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(1.0).minimize(loss)

# the two feed dictionaries
feeddict_train = {x: x_train, y: y_train}
feeddict_test = {x: x_test, y: y_test}

### training
# run 500 times using all the X and Y
# print out the loss and any other interesting info
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    train_loss, test_loss = [], []
    for step in range(500):
        loss_train, _ = sess.run([loss, train], feed_dict=feeddict_train)
        train_loss.append(loss_train)

        # insert whatever logic is needed 

        # under the same tensorflow graph (in the session), use another feed dictionary 
        loss_test = sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feeddict_test)
        test_loss.append(loss_test)

plt.plot(train_loss, 'r', label='train_loss')
plt.plot(test_loss, 'b', label='test_loss')
plt.legend(loc='best')
```

By running the code, you can see both the test loss and the training loss is getting smaller. And you can insert whatever logic is needed after the train loss is evaluated.

One very important thing is when I use `feeddict_test` in `sess.run(loss, feed_dict=feeddict_test)`, the model is not trained, but only the test loss is evaluated on the test dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try to understand the concept as well as possible and then try to implement the idea you provided

Comment: Sorry, do you have any document to read in order to understand that step ? or could you please add more details explaining that step you added? does your reply mean that deep network will do training till such threshold is achieved and then run test, right ?

Comment: @Gze you are welcome, you can watch [this](https://youtu.be/6SlgtELqOWc) video to understand the basics of tensorflow. I have added more details to my answer, maybe it is enough to address your confusions.